# Get frequency of a column in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, count

I have a column with values like 1,1,2,1,... and I would want to get the frequency of 1 and 2, I did

```
SELECT count(column)
FROM table
WHERE column = 1;

SELECT count(column)
FROM table
WHERE column = 2;
```

But, could I take the frequency with a more direct way?

Answer (score 42):

Use aggregate functions

```
 Select column, count(*)
 From   table
 Group By column
```

This will return one row that contains the count, for each distinct value in column

Answer (score 5):

One row each value:

```
select column 'value', count (column) 'Frequency'
from table
group by column
```

if only 2 values this give you both results in one row

```
select sum(case when column=1 then 1 else 0 end) as '1 Frequency',
        sum(case when column=2 then 1 else 0 end) as '2 Frequency'
from table
```

Comment: @user_012314112 Have you tried my answer? Let me know if it works or need some tunning.

Answer (score 0):

You can try distinct function, like this

```
SELECT count( distinct column) FROM table;
```