# How to count and sort occurances of entries in a column in SQL?

Tags: sql

I have a column in my table `completed` named `completed at` (with a space).
It contains either a `blank entry`, or `value1`, `value2`, `value3`.

I would like to run a SQL query that counts the amounts of time value1, value2, value3 etc. occurs, ordered by descending order.

I would like it to look like this:

| Count | Location |
| --- | --- |
| 49 | value2 |
| 18 | value1 |
| 1 | value3 |

Is this possible to do?

Comment: Please provide a [mre] and also choose the used rdms

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24767130/get-frequency-of-a-column-in-sql-server/24767214#24767214

Answer (score 1):

For ANSI SQL I would write this. If you need other kind of SQL please specify and I will glade to update my answer.

```
SELECT 
   COUNT(*) as Count,
   "completed at" as Location
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY "completed at" 
ORDER BY 1 DESC
```

Comment: I guess you wanted to use double quotes rather than single quotes - you want to use what is in most dbms known as Qualified Name. `'completed at'` is just a string constant, with such expression there is just a single group with total count.

Comment: @TomášZáluský I think it but the OP doesn't provide wich SQL is working and I usually work with SQL Server and I write it on the fly. I'll glad if you could or want edit the answer.

Comment: Product specific answer to a question with no dbms specified. At least tell us which dbms this is for.

Comment: @jarlh you are right. Edited. Thanks and sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Put the column name in square brackets so you don't have to worry about empty spaces.

```
SELECT 
   COUNT(*) AS Count,
   [completed at] AS Location
FROM tablename
GROUP BY [completed at]
ORDER BY Count DESC
```